# Настройка нескольких виртуальных экранов в VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, monitor

Мне нужно сымитировать наличие нескольких дисплеев в гостевой ОС (Windows 7) в VirtualBox (физический монитор лишь один). Вроде бы в настройках выставил кол-во мониторов равным 2, но в гостевой ОС второй монитор обозначается чёрным цветом и пункта "расширить экран" я не нахожу.

[image]

[image]

Обнаружил, что в меню ВМ "Вид -> Виртуальный экран 2" команда "Включить" не работает. VirtualBox стоит самый свежий - 6.1.30.

[Лог работы](https://pastebin.com/2iwLtpQu)

Что делать?

Comment: Установить дополнения гостевой ОС, наверное?

Comment: Они установлены.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так нельзя сделать, так как вам необходимо указать гипервизору на какой хост вам необходимо прикрепить виртуальный монитор. Вот так у меня выглядит настройка для запуска виртуальной машины с двумя мониторами.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]